# Move form relative to location clicked

Tags: c#, .net

I have a form which can be moved when the user clicks and drags in a border area. The implementations I've seen all lock to the current mouse position, so that when the form is moved, the form jumps so that the mouse is in the upper-left corner. I'd like to change it so that it behaves like a normal windows form, and the form stays at the same position relative to the mouse when moved. My current code looks like this:

```
Point locationClicked;
bool isMouseDown = false;

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseDown = true;
    locationClicked = new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
}

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseDown = false;
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isMouseDown && targetCell == new Point(-1, -1) && (mouseLocation.X < margin.X || mouseLocation.Y < margin.Y ||
        mouseLocation.X > margin.X + cellSize.Width * gridSize.Width ||
        mouseLocation.Y > margin.Y + cellSize.Height * gridSize.Height))
    {
        this.Location = new Point(e.Location.X - locationClicked.X, e.Location.Y - locationClicked.Y);
    }
}
```

When I drag the window, it behaves similarly to what I want. The form flickers between two locations on the screen, one of which moves at about half the rate of the mouse. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Just handle the `WM_NCHITTEST` message appropriately, and Windows will do all of the window moving for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Point locationClicked;
    bool dragForm = false;

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            locationClicked = new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
            if (isMouseDown && targetCell == new Point(-1, -1) && (mouseLocation.X < margin.X || mouseLocation.Y < margin.Y ||
                mouseLocation.X > margin.X + cellSize.Width * gridSize.Width ||
                mouseLocation.Y > margin.Y + cellSize.Height * gridSize.Height))
            {
                dragForm = true;
            }
        }

    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragForm)
        {
            this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + (e.X - locationClicked.X), this.Location.Y + (e.Y - locationClicked.Y));
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragForm = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: That works, but it causes an exception when I generate my borders (I actually used this to my advantage, so it's good), however it stops working after the form is dragged by the bottom or right margin. Any idea why?

Comment: Solved the problem by resetting `targetCell`. Thanks!